# AdMob stops providing ads

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, admob

I have released Android game with AdMob ads. One day (Aug 7 2017) ads stopped showing. But ads works with Google test Ad id and other account Ad ids. Probably some issue with my account. What is the problem?
The game was released almost year before that and ads worked.
AdMob support doesn't responding to multiple requests I sent.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not appear to be a programming related question within the scope defined by the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdMob stops providing ads from **Aug 7 2017**, I am sure it's not due to you've lower version of Mobile Ad SDK.

Cross check version of your Mobile Ad SDK.

---

As Ads stopped form 7 Aug, check your admob associated email account, you may have email regarding problem. You can find the **issue ID** at the bottom of your email notification.

Review the notification email (which should include an issue ID) carefully for a description of the violation and what steps, if any, you can take to fix the issue. Once you've made the appropriate changes to your app, you can request a review of your app by submitting an [AdMob policy appeal](https://support.google.com/admob/contact/appeal_policy_violation).

*No email notification received for my app regarding any policy violation so I've not any Issue ID.*

Submit [Can't appeal AdMob policy violation](https://support.google.com/admob/contact/cant_appeal_policy_violation) form.

Comment: Thank for advice!No emails about violation have been received. I just sent appeal form.

Comment: Just received answer "your billing address hasn't been verified and that is why the ad serving has stopped.". Come on, they stop providing service even without notification about it.

Comment: [Here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2772302?hl=en) is the info, If a PIN isn’t entered within 4 months of the generation of your first PIN, ads will stop showing in your apps.

Comment: Petro shm how did you send appeal when i try to send appeal they ask for issue ID witch include in email , but they never send me any email

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading your admob sdk to the latest one. admob periodically deprecates its older versions.

the most recent cull is for 7.0.0

> 14 November 2017: Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK versions lower than 7.0.0 (Android & iOS)
>
> Starting on  23 January 2018, we will no longer support Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK versions lower than 7.0.0 for Android or iOS. To continue serving mobile ads from AdMob, Ad Exchange, or DFP after this date, please upgrade to the latest Google Mobile Ads SDK:

https://support.google.com/admob/release-notes/3369520?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=7383088&authuser=0

Comment: Thanks for reply! I also tested with Google test Ad id and other account Ad ids and ads are showing. Probably some issue with my account.